# One controller to 2 fxmls (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, fxml, controllers

Is possible to connect two FXML (JavaFX) files to one controller?
I can't do this with changing "fx:controller" in each FXML file...

Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible to use the same controller class for multiple FXML files, but your code will be really hard to follow, and it's a very bad idea. (Also note that using the  `fx:controller` attribute, you will have a different controller *instance* each time you call `FXMLLoader.load(...)`, even if you use the same controller *class*.) Use a different controller class for each FXML file.

Comment: There is never any need for multiple FXML files to share the same controller. If you need to communicate between the controllers, use the techniques described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Although, it can be done, *I do not recommend this approach*.

Don't place a `fx:controller` attribute in either FXML.  Create a new controller and set the same controller into separate FXMLLoader instances.

```
CustomerDialogController dialogController = 
    new CustomerDialogController(param1, param2);

FXMLLoader summaryloader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
        "customerSummary.fxml"
    )
);
summaryLoader.setController(dialogController);
Pane summaryPane = (Pane) summaryLoader.load();

FXMLLoader detailsLoader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource(
        "customerDetails.fxml"
    )
);
detailsLoader.setController(detailsController);
Pane detailsPane = (Pane) detailsLoader.load();

SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(
    summaryPane, 
    detailsPane
);
```

> I want to create one controller, because I have problem with sending data beetwen controlers

IMO using a shared controller just to share data is not the preferred solution for this.

Instead, either share the data between multiple controllers, for examples of this see:

- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

There is a further example here:

- [JavaFX8 list bindings similar to xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042109/javafx8-list-bindings-similar-to-xaml)

Even better, see:

- [Applying MVC With JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)
- https://edencoding.com/mvc-in-javafx/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `fx:root` construct instead of `fx:controller`. It is explained in the [Custom Components section of the FXML docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html). I have used it in [this example for my students](http://svanimpe.be/blog/ogly.html) if you want a bigger code example.

Using this approach, creating views and controllers will be a lot easier and flexible. You will be able to share data between and connect controllers like you would any other objects in your application (for example: by passing data via the constructor or setter methods).

If you're using SceneBuilder you'll simply need to remove the controller reference and check the box "Use fx:root". Then rework your code as shown in the examples.