# JavaFX Label not updating with setText()

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml, scenebuilder

I have done a lot of searching and cannot seem to find a solution to my problem, I am trying to get the label *selectedName* to update when the user enters his/her name inside Intro.fxml and appear on Main.fxml. However it still appears as default_user which is set in the initialize method. Admittedly the code is a bit of a mess, but it's just a little project I'm working on.

**LogicController.java** not the whole file

```
public class LogicController{ 

/** CLASS OBJECTS
 * 
 */

private LoadWords loadWords = new LoadWords();
private GameLogic game = new GameLogic();

/** AUDIO FILES 
 * items used for audio
 * All wavs are free
 * provided on freesound.org
 * **/

final URL resource = getClass().getResource("sounds/beep.wav");
final AudioClip menuClick = new AudioClip(resource.toString());

/** OTHER DECLARATIONS
 * other variables
 * 
 * 
 */

@FXML public ChoiceBox<String> difficultyBox = new ChoiceBox<String>();
@FXML public ObservableList<String> difficultyBoxList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Easiest", "Easy", "Medium", "Hard");
@FXML public String selectedDifficulty; 
@FXML public TextField myName;
@FXML public Label selectedName = new Label(); 

@FXML  
public void initialize()
{
  difficultyBox.setItems(difficultyBoxList);
  selectedName.setText("default_player");


}


@FXML
public void loadSerial(MouseEvent mouseEvent) { 

    menuClick.play();
    loadWords.startSequential();    

    game.setAllLists(loadWords.getAllLists());
    game.setDifficulty(difficultyBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString());
    game.setName(myName.getText());
    selectedName.setText(game.getName().toString());

    try{

        Node  source = (Node)  mouseEvent.getSource(); 
        Stage intro  = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
        intro.close();          

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")); 
        root.setId("pane");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 506);
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

        primaryStage.setTitle("x");
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

      }catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }


}
```

**Intro.fxml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="fx" prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="923.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4f0f41;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LogicController">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="538.0" prefWidth="923.0">
         <children>
            <Pane prefHeight="545.0" prefWidth="929.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="265.0" layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="103.0" prefWidth="394.0" style="-fx-font-family: Paperland; -fx-font-size: 90;" stylesheets="@application.css" text="FANGMAN" textFill="WHITE">
                     <effect>
                        <Glow />
                     </effect>
                     <font>
                        <Font size="66.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="265.0" layoutY="69.0" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="79.0" style="-fx-font-family: Paperland; -fx-font-size: 40;" stylesheets="@application.css" text="THE" textFill="WHITE">
                     <effect>
                        <Glow />
                     </effect>
                  </Label>
                  <Label layoutX="694.0" layoutY="24.0" text="An adaptation by Benjamin Meysner" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <FlowPane layoutX="266.0" layoutY="288.0" prefHeight="225.0" prefWidth="378.0">
                     <children>
                        <GridPane prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="398.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="171.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="171.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="265.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="64.0" />
                              <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="233.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="152.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="51.0" minHeight="5.0" prefHeight="48.0" />
                            <RowConstraints maxHeight="172.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="109.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints maxHeight="78.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="41.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                              <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <ImageView id="zomb" fx:id="zomb" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" onMouseClicked="#loadSerial" onMouseEntered="#zombieHover" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-cursor: hand;" styleClass="zomb" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@images/chtr1.png" />
                                 </image>
                                 <effect>
                                    <Glow />
                                 </effect>
                              </ImageView>
                              <ImageView id="skul" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" onMouseClicked="#loadParallel" onMouseEntered="#skulHover" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-cursor: hand;" styleClass="skul" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@images/chtr3.png" />
                                 </image>
                                 <effect>
                                    <Glow />
                                 </effect>
                              </ImageView>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" style="-fx-font-family: Paperland;" text="OR" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="50.0" />
                                 </font>
                                 <effect>
                                    <Glow />
                                 </effect>
                              </Label>
                              <Label text="Serial" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                              <Label text="Parallel" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children>
                  </FlowPane>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="104.0" fitWidth="113.0" layoutX="156.0" layoutY="90.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@images/drac.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="252.0" layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="52.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Now enter your name..." textFill="WHITE" />
                  <Label layoutX="252.0" layoutY="203.0" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="To begin a new game, select a difficulty setting..." textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true" />
                  <TextField fx:id="myName" layoutX="405.0" layoutY="276.0" promptText="Enter name...">
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow height="71.4" radius="30.7525" spread="0.13" width="53.61" />
                     </effect></TextField>
                  <Label layoutX="115.0" layoutY="281.0" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Finally select a load option (Serial or Parallel)" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true" />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="difficultyBox" layoutX="404.0" layoutY="225.0" prefWidth="150.0" value="Easiest">
                     <effect>
                        <DropShadow height="0.0" radius="29.2125" spread="0.19" width="118.85" />
                     </effect>
                  </ChoiceBox>
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane style="-fx-background-color: #4f0f41;" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.LogicController">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="506.0" prefWidth="900.0" stylesheets="@application.css">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="197.0" fitWidth="183.0" layoutX="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@images/drac.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="37.0" layoutY="223.0" text="Welcome" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label fx:id="selectedName" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="218.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="121.0" text="  " textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="13.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect>
            </Label>
            <Pane layoutX="24.0" layoutY="211.0" opacity="0.45" prefHeight="127.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: BLACK;">
               <children>
                  <GridPane layoutX="13.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="153.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Games Won" textFill="WHITE" />
                        <Label text="Games Lost" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Win Ratio" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="0" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="0" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="0%" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="246.0" layoutY="61.0" opacity="0.45" prefHeight="421.0" prefWidth="633.0" style="-fx-background-color: BLACK;" />
            <Button layoutX="355.0" layoutY="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="save game" />
            <Pane layoutX="25.0" layoutY="373.0" opacity="0.45" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: BLACK;" />
            <Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="load game" />
            <Button layoutX="469.0" layoutY="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newWord" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="new word" />
            <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="484.0" text="message box" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="28.0" layoutY="346.0" text="statistics" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label layoutX="246.0" layoutY="484.0" text="game view" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**IMAGES HERE**
[intro.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOWWc.jpg)
[main.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb1Q7.jpg)
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Both your FXML files have the same controller. You need not need the `fx:controller` in both of them. Here is a question on [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464857/one-controller-to-2-fxmls-javafx)

Comment: @Shashwat Actually, they don't "have the same controller". Each time either of these FXML files is loaded, a new controller is created: however the controllers for both FXML files are from the same class. (There is a big difference between "being the same object" and "two objects being from the same class".) It is generally a very bad idea to do this: there should be a different controller *class* for each FXML file.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable Is already annotated `@FXML` so no need to instantiate it:

```
//Wrong
@FXML public Label selectedName = new Label ();

//Correct
@FXML public Label selectedName;
```

Edit:

Same for other annotated items and try implementing the Initializable :

```
LogicController implements Initializable{
```

Comment: If i take it out I get a null pointer exception `code`
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.LogicController.initialize(LogicController.java:56)
 ... 27 more

Comment: Try to post the full code or just the line 56 of your `LogicController`

Comment: Still get the null pointer exception thrown for the same line,       selectedName.setText("default_player");

Comment: Line 56 :       selectedName.setText("default_player");

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The controller instance used with `Intro.fxml` is not the same instance as the one used with `Main.fxml`. You need to specify the controller instance before loading the fxml to use the same instance:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
loader.setController(this);
Parent root = loader.load();

// fill data to the field just created when loading the fxml
selectedName.setText(game.getName().toString());
```

(This requires the removal of the `fx:controller` attribute from `Main.fxml`.)

Note that this way initialize is called twice. It would IMHO be better to use seperate controllers.

There are multiple ways of passing info to a controller of a fxml file that could be better suited than the above approach, e.g. accessing the controller instance created by `FXMLLoader`.

Note that initializing fields that should be injected from the fxml to prevent a NPE is seldomly a good idea, since this is just a symptom of the error and the value you initialize the field with has no connection to the objects created from the fxml.

Comment: I removed the instantiate bit from Label selectedName, and added the following inside the loadSerial method.     `code`

      
      
        try{        
            Node  source = (Node)  mouseEvent.getSource(); 
            Stage intro  = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
            intro.close();        
         
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            Parent root = loader.load();            
`code` .. still get a null pointer for the label

Comment: also removed the fx:controller attribute from main.fxml

Comment: @benjay_uk FWIW I would not even try to use the same controller, or controllers from the same class, for two different FXML files. Define a different controller class for each FXML file and communicate the data between them when you need.

Comment: @benjay_uk If you use the same controller instance, every access to the injected fields needs to happen after the call to `load()`. In this case you're accessing the field from the `initialize` method which cannot initialize something not injected by the fxml. BTW: You assign the content in the fxml anyways, so why overwrite the value in the `initialize` method with a constant?